# Sales Order Grid Record Count is Broken when GROUP BY used to add Products to Grid

Tags: admin, orders, collection

I have extended my sales order grid in a custom module (my first ever!) to add product names, skus and various other fields to the grid and it all works fine EXCEPT that the total number of records always shows 1 and the pagination doesn't work.

I know that to fix this I have to override the function getSelectCountSql() in the class Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection with the following code (found elsewhere on this site):

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{   
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

    // Count doesn't work with group by columns keep the group by 
    if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->distinct(true);
        $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
    } else {
        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
    }
    return $countSelect;
```

}

and if I replace the core code everything works fine.

BUT how do I do this properly in my custom module??  I have the following in my config.xml

```
<models>
   <salesordergrid>
         <class>MyCompany_SalesOrderGrid_Model</class>  
         <resourceModel>salesordergrid_resource</resourceModel>
    </salesordergrid>       
    <salesordergrid_resource>
        <class>MyCompany_SalesOrderGrid_Model_Resource</class>
    </salesordergrid_resource>
    <sales_resource>
        <rewrite>
             <order_collection>MyCompany_SalesOrderGrid_Model_Resource_Order_Collection</order_collection>
        </rewrite>
    </sales_resource>
</models>
```

and the following custom class:

```
class MyCompany_SalesOrderGrid_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function getSelectCountSql() {   
        //code as above..
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.  Please can somebody tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection` rather than `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract`.